# How to stop this sequence?

Tags: ios, function, animation, callback

i am animating a frame, through this code, which is easily understandable in code, now i am trying to stop this sequence after 20 time means in completion parentheses i need to call that function for 20 times only: how can i do that?

```
    -(void)conveyComplete:(UIView*)v
    {
     [self convey:v delay:0];
    }
    -(void)convey:(UIView*)v delay:(int)nDelay
    {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                          delay:nDelay
                        options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                     animations: ^
     {
         CGRect rPos = v.frame;

         NSLog(@"x:%f y:%f vFrame:%f vFrame:%f" , rPos.origin.x,rPos.origin.y,v.frame.origin.x,v.frame.origin.y);    
             rPos.origin.x -= 5;
             rPos.origin.y -=100;

             v.frame = rPos;

     }
                     completion: ^(BOOL finished)
     {
         [self conveyComplete:v];
          NSLog(@"I:%i, F:%i",i,f);
     }];

}
```

Comment: Where is the code to stop animation?

Comment: You can create a timer  and global variable. In your method `variable++;` and at the end check `if(variable>20) timer invalidate;`

Comment: As per his code he don't need time just check something like if(variable<=20) {[self conveyComplete:v]; }

Comment: @Iducool yes i did the same before you just prescribed..anyways thankyou very much..

Comment: @Iducool please guide me how can i reset the v.frame to its orignal default values when my condition is true?

Comment: at proper place store your v.frame into CGRect and after the animation just set that rect into v.frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have made a global integer:

```
int i=1;


 -(void)conveyComplete:(UIView*)v{

  [self convey:v delay:0];
  }

 -(void)convey:(UIView*)v delay:(int)nDelay{

 [UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                  delay:nDelay
                options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
             animations: ^
   {   

   CGRect rPos = v.frame;
   i+=1;// then increase +1 every time it runs
 NSLog(@"x:%f y:%f vFrame:%f vFrame:%f" , rPos.origin.x,rPos.origin.y,v.frame.origin.x,v.frame.origin.y);


     rPos.origin.x -= 5;

     rPos.origin.y -=100;

     v.frame = rPos;

 }

completion: ^(BOOL finished)
 {
 if(i<20){
 [self conveyComplete:v];
 }
  NSLog(@"I:%i, F:%i",i,f);
  }];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As your function does only animation, one possible solution is not to call function 20 times, but instead set repeat count of animation with [setAnimationRepeatCount:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationRepeatCount%3a) method.
It'll looks something similar to this:

```
[UIView UIView animateWithDuration:.5
                  delay:nDelay
                options:(UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | ...)
             animations: ^{
                 // Do your animation stuff

                 [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:20];
             }
             completion:NULL];
```

But one other aspect that is worth regarding is whether you need to repeat animation 20 times at all. All you do is just stepwise shifting of you view frame. Why not to animate this at once by setting appropriate offsets and animation duration?